# Can't run chromedriver and google-chrome-stable at the same time

Tags: java, google-chrome, chromium

Up until now I've been using `chromium` as my default browser and have been running java-selenium test automation with `chromedriver` (which I've downloaded and manually specified its location to the automation progmatically).

I've been able to use both side-by-side, until today. I installed the defacto `google-chrome-stable` application, and now if I have it open `chromedriver` fails to instantiate an instance and the automation hangs.

If I close `google-chrome-stable` and open chromium (as I am doing now to ask this question), I can run test automation however unity shows `chromedriver` with the `google-chrome-stable` icon in the launcher. I suspect that this is a symptom of what is happening, but I can't imagine what.

How do fix this so I can run them side-by-side, as I used to do with `chromium`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through and doing some research, I realized that I had a very important misunderstanding of how `chromedriver` worked. From their [README.txt](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/README.txt&q=file:test/chromedriver/README.txt&sq=package:chromium&l=1):

> ChromeDriver will use the system installed Chrome by default.
>
> ... [section omitted for brevity/relevance] ...
>
> =====Architecture=====
>
> ChromeDriver is shipped separately from Chrome. It controls Chrome out of process through DevTools. ChromeDriver is a
>   standalone server which communicates with the WebDriver client via the
>   WebDriver wire protocol, which is essentially synchronous JSON
>   commands over HTTP. WebDriver clients are available in many languages,
>   and many are available from the open source selenium/webdriver
>   project: http://code.google.com/p/selenium. ChromeDriver uses the
>   webserver from net/server.

This fundamental part of how it works is why `google-chrome-stable` started causing issues with it. It also means that even though I thought I was using `chromium` side-by-side with `chromedriver`, I was probably mistakenly sharing the same `chromium` instance at the same time.